# Responsive navbar working on the computer but not on the phone

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, responsive

So my client found this nice looking responsive navbar on codepen and wants to use it on their website.  I decided to do a test by downloading it and putting it on a [test page](http://ecfleming.com/test/index.html) on the own domain.

Before jumping ahead I downloaded the file and tested it on my own domain and some problems came up. It worked perfectly fine on the computer.  When the window was stretched to full screen, it was set up hike a horizontal menu and when I shrunk the screen it became a drop-down menu.
However when it was viewed on an actual phone the menu still showed up as a horizontal menu.
[image]

I have tried messing with the CSS document with no luck. I even tried altering the @media (max-width: 768px) thinking it might need a higher number. I can not find anything in the Javascript code that could be wrong.  Do any of you know why it might not be working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You 
Ethan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a viewport problem. In the `<head>` of your HTML page, try adding the following code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Phones generally try to fit the normal computer-width page onto the phone screen, so they have to be told to display the website in its actual scale!

Comment: SUCCESS...IT WORKS
I'm really surprised because I thought it was something wrong wit the CSS or JavaScript. Thank you so much